# How to insert text with DOM-Methods at the position of the JavaScript-call

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to obscure e-mail-addresses on my website using a javascript-method "saveMailAddress", which takes "name", "domain" and "TLD" as parameters. Afterwards this method should add a node "a" to the DOM-tree.

But how can I find out the position where to add the object?

In HTML it should look like (generated by a PHP script):

```
<p>
    The E-Mail of user XXX is:
    <script type="text/javascript">
    saveMailAdresses("superman", "comic", "com");
    </script>.
</p>
```

In the javascript part the a-Elemnt should be generated:

```
function saveMailAdresses(name, domain, tld) {
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.appendChild(
        document.createTextNode("linktext");
    );
    ...
}
```

But how can I place the new element to the parent-Element in which the function is called?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

```
<p id='mailadress'>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write(saveMailAdresses("name", "domain", "tld");
    </script>
</p>


function saveMailAdresses(name, domain, tld) {
        return "<a href=''>test</a>";
}
```

Comment: But the onload-eventHandler is only allowed within <body> and <frameset> (german source: http://de.selfhtml.org/javascript/sprache/eventhandler.htm#onload ), and also the w3-validator gives the error ´there is no attribute "ONLOAD"´. e.g. try ´<span onload="alert('test');">test</span>´

Comment: Then you have to give the `<p>` Element an ID, that you can access it. I'll update the code above

Comment: Is it not possible to do it easily without IDs? and without an onload? I never know how many E-Mail-Adresses are on the page,... Well, at least the onload could be avided by calling the javascript-function to show the mail-Adress directly after the p-element, and could generate random IDs with PHP, but I'm still not satisfied,...

Answer (score 0):

Does the A tag that is inserted include the actual email address in the href?  If so then the email address will still be obtainable through any modern browser's debugging tools, or just by clicking on the link to open the email client with the address in the To field.

If you still want to do it you could create an array at the start of the page that takes an object containing the element and the three variables above for each address to be added, add an object to the array for each address, and then at the end of the page loop through the array and call the function on each of the objects (using your method signature with an additional element argument).

If you really want to protect your email addresses you could have a form that the user fills in and posts back to the server and then have the server send the email to the correct person based on the values in the form (i.e. dropdown for which department etc).  In this way the client will never see the email address.

Answer (score 0):

You could use HTML5 `data-` attributes. This example uses jQuery for simplicity, but you could write it in pure DOM if you needed to:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $(".email").each(function (){
      var $this = $(this),
          address = $this.data("username") + "@" + $this.data("domain") + "." + $this.data("tld"),
          $link = $("<a>").attr("href", "mailto:" + address).html("link text");

      $this.append($link);
    });
  });​
</script>

<p>
  My e-mail address:
  <span class="email" data-username="someone" data-domain="example" data-tld="com"></span>
<p>
```

[This jsFiddle is a working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/bclennox/jMWHs/)